# ¿Cómo consigo el útimo día del mes anterior en Python?

Tags: python, date

Hoy es `01/02/2018` y necesito el `31/01/2018`. Para hacerlo utilicé esta función pero me resta un valor en los días y me queda en `0/02/2018`:

```
final = time.strftime(str((int(time.strftime("%d")))-1) + "/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Qué mejor que utilizar el paquete [Arrow de Python](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para simplificar esta información:

```
>>> arrow.now()  # ahora
<Arrow [2018-08-16T12:36:06.247982+02:00]>

>>> arrow.now().shift(months=-1)  # hace un mes
<Arrow [2018-07-16T12:36:15.104884+02:00]>

>>> arrow.now().shift(months=-1).ceil('month')  # último momento del mes anterior
<Arrow [2018-07-31T23:59:59.999999+02:00]>
```

Luego es solo cuestión de convertirlo a string o a lo que quieras usando `.date()` o `.format()`:

```
>>> arrow.now().shift(months=-1).ceil('month').date()
datetime.date(2018, 7, 31)

>>> arrow.now().shift(months=-1).ceil('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
'31/07/2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

Con eso pude hacerlo.

```
ultimoDiaMesAnterior=datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)+datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! Pero creo que tu respuesta podría beneficiarse si además explicaras por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos.